# using union in a construct sparql query

Tags: select, union, sparql, describe

I have an `rdf` graph with several entries. Now I want to get all related triples to a given id. This is my sparql query:

```
select ?s ?p ?o from <http://localhost:8890/DAV/ranking> where {
 {<http://seekda.com/providers/cdyne.com/PhoneNotify> so:hasEndpoint ?s.
 ?s ?p ?o} union
 {<http://seekda.com/providers/cdyne.com/PhoneNotify> ?p ?o}
}
```

The ID in this case is `<seekda.com/providers/cdyne.com/PhoneNotify>`.

But I need a graph query (`construct` or `describe`). So I think I have to pack them togheter with an `union`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: there is no difference.

The longer answer is: think about SPARQL queries as having two parts.

1. The query (WHERE) part, which produces a list of variable bindings (although some variables may be unbound).
2. The part which puts together the results. `SELECT`, `ASK`, `CONSTRUCT`, or `DESCRIBE`.

`SELECT *` is effectively what the query returns. `SELECT ?v1 ?v2` takes results and produces another result set with the other variables removed. `ASK` just looks to see if there are any results.

`CONSTRUCT` uses a template to make RDF from the results. For each result row it binds the variables and adds the statements to the result model. If a template triple contains an unbound variable it is skipped.

`DESCRIBE` is the most unusual, since it takes each result node, finds triples associated with it, and adds them to a result model. Unlike the others it can contain more information than the query matches.

So having `UNION`, `OPTIONAL`, whatever, in the query is allowed for all forms. They may lead to missing triples due to unbound variables.

<strike>Your query doesn't make much sense. It's no different to `{?s ?p ?o}`. What are you trying to do?</strike> Ok, makes more sense now.

Given clarifications below it sounds like you want the following:

```
construct { <http://seekda.com/providers/cdyne.com/PhoneNotify> ?p ?o }
from <http://localhost:8890/DAV/ranking> 
where {
  { <http://seekda.com/providers/cdyne.com/PhoneNotify> so:hasEndpoint ?s.
    ?s ?p ?o }
  union
  { <http://seekda.com/providers/cdyne.com/PhoneNotify> ?p ?o }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer.
ok, what im trying to do is:
i have an rdf graph with several entries. now i want to get all related triples to a given id(in this case the id is <http://seekda.com/providers/cdyne.com/PhoneNotify>). as i need it in rdf, i have to use construct and as there are some transitive relations i have to pack them togheter with an union(?).
i hope this clarifyies my problem.
best regards
simon

ps: there was an error in my query, i corrected it, i think now it makes more sense :)

Comment: Ah, I see. So you want info about this thing (PhoneNotify), and the endpoint?

Comment: You mentioned 'transitive relations'. Is the idea that the 'endpoint' relations apply to 'PhoneNotify'?